# Controller Action being executed by css and map files

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i'm trying to integrate angularjs html5mode with my asp.net mvc application. i've done numerous searches and they pretty much all say add the following to your web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="api/" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

For the most part everything is working as expected except now i notice that some file requests are triggering my controller action method to fire. for example, if i do a view source and click on any of the .css links my controller action gets executed. i'm sure there are more as well because when i add a break point it is being called multiple times.

here is my route config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

here is an example of a url that calls my controller action

```
http://localhost:63952/app/assets/css/style.css
```

any help would be great!

Comment: I can't really tell if there are any issues witht he web.config, but you could add an `IgnoreRoute` for the .css extension: `routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");`

Comment: Can you show the URLs being hit when you observe the issue?

Comment: it just seems strange no one else has noticed this. makes me thing i am missing something.

Comment: @G.Stoynev added to my post

Comment: You can simply ignore all of the files in "/app/assets": `routes.IgnoreRoute("app/assets/{*pathInfo}");`

Comment: OK I just left work I'll give that a shot in a few

Comment: @Nava-Prev.Queti did not work. i wonder if the rewrite is overrides the ignore routes.

Comment: It sounds like you may have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` or have an MVC handler configured to use `path="*.*" `, `path="*.css" ` or something along those lines.